# How to create sound from the microphone in JavaScript and play it in real-time using Java?

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, spring-websocket, microphone, mediadevices

I don't know how to send real-time audio to Java.

On javascript:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    }).then((mediaStream) => {
        const audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        const mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
        var socketMicroStream = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/microstream");
        socketMicroStream.onopen = function(event) {
            socketMicroStream.send(socketMicroStream);
        };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
    });
```

On java using websocket

```
    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String stream) {
        try {
            // get buffer audio
            // play audio
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }
```

I tried using MediaRecorder in JavaScript, but the audio is choppy. Please help.